# How to display the records on edit page?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am new in MySQL and I am using CodeIgniter. I have three tables called `lead, document`, and `bank`.

Now what I am doing is, In the `lead` table I am inserting the customer personal information which is unique. In the `document` table, I am inserting the user documents. In the `bank` table, I am inserting the bank records. It can be multiple.

There is no issue with insertion. I am getting the issue while fetching the data from the database.

Now table structure is

**lead**

```
id  | name   | mobile     | email  
1   | asdff  |1234567831  |asd@gmail.com
2   | kjhgg  |1231231231  |mnhg@gmail.com
3   | qwsde  |1231233212  |oiuk@gmail.com
<!--many more-->
```

**document**

```
doc_id  |doc_name    | doc_date  | lead_id |date_of_added
1       |asdasd      |2019-06-24 | 1       |2019-06-16 17:31:07
2       |oiuytr      |2019-06-24 | 2       |2019-06-16 17:31:07
3       |okjhyt      |2019-06-25 | 3       |2019-06-20 20:12:09
<!--many more-->
```

**bank**

```
bank_id  | bankname  | lead_id |date_of_added
1        | sdasdas   | 1       |2019-06-20 11:41:34
2        | asdasdasd | 1       |2019-06-21 10:41:34
3        | asdakjkh  | 2       |2019-06-21 14:23:12
4        | qwerfgvf  | 1       |2019-06-21 23:56:25
<!--many more-->
```

There is no connection between the document and the bank till now.  should I connect using id?

**Model**

```
public function getconfirmLeadinfo($id){
   return  $result = $this->db->select('*')
                     ->from('lead')
                     ->join('document','lead.id=document.lead_id','LEFT')
                     ->join('bank','lead.id=bank.lead_id','LEFT')
                     ->where('lead.id',$id)
                     ->get()
                     ->result();
  }
```

I am getting the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => asdff
            [mobile] => 1234567831
            [email] => asd@gmail.com
            [doc_id] => 1
            [doc_name] => asdasd
            [doc_date] => 2019-06-24
            [lead_id] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2019-06-16 17:31:07
            [bank_id] => 1
            [bankname] => sdasdas
            [lead_id] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2019-06-20 11:41:34

         )
[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => asdff
            [mobile] => 1234567831
            [email] => asd@gmail.com
            [doc_id] => 1
            [doc_name] => asdasd
            [doc_date] => 2019-06-24
            [lead_id] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2019-06-16 17:31:07
            [bank_id] => 2
            [bankname] => asdasdasd
            [lead_id] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2019-06-21 10:41:34

         )
[2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => asdff
            [mobile] => 1234567831
            [email] => asd@gmail.com
            [doc_id] => 1
            [doc_name] => asdasd
            [doc_date] => 2019-06-24
            [lead_id] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2019-06-16 17:31:07
            [bank_id] => 4
            [bankname] => qwerfgvf
            [lead_id] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2019-06-21 23:56:25

         )
)
```

Now I am on edit page and I have to display the data.

```
if ($post){?>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $post->name;?>">
<input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $post->mobile;?>">
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $post->email;?>">

<input type="text" name="doc_name" value="<?php echo $post->doc_name;?>">
<input type="text" name="doc_date" value="<?php echo $post->doc_date;?>">
 how do I display my bank details here? should I use something like this
    <?php
 foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
<input type="text" name="bank[]" value="$value->bankname">
}
}?>
```

Would you help me out?

Comment: use dropdown to show multiple bank details

Comment: @PHPGeek, dropdown? why? Please check my bank table and my output. You will understand my issue.

Comment: you can use two query. in first query retrive user details and second query retrive bank details because it is multiple per user, then you can use loop to display multiple bank details.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, Yes, I think you understand my issue. If I use two queries then how do I return from the model?

Comment: dont use join because with join you will get duplicate user records. so first get user data and in other query retrive bank details and fill in one variable and use it in view.

Comment: see my answer, you will get idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two separate query as below::

```
$data = [];
$lead = $this->db->select('*')->from('lead')->get()->row();
$data['lead'] = $lead;
if($lead){
  $bank = $this->db->select('*')->where('lead_id', $lead->lead_id)->from('bank')->get()->result();
$data['bank '] = $bank ;
}


// you can retrive documet like bank details


return $data
```

Then you can pass `$data` to view and use `lead` and `bank` variable if it exist.

Comment: @Devshi, Give me sometime to check your answer

Comment: @Devshi, I think I can use join in first query to get the output of the lead and document table..correct?

Comment: yes you can but with different query it will more easy.

Comment: You mean to say something like same as bank query?

Comment: yes, you will having single record of user and multiple record of bank and document, so retrive one record of user with `row()` and retrive multiple record of `bank` and `document` with `result()` and you can use it in the view.

Comment: That's cool!..give me some time to implement your answer with my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to take the distinct record from the table, i can see the result is duplicated 
   all details are same , why u cant use  INNER JOIN instead of left.
2. You will get single record by using ->row() instead of ->result();
3. Then you can use the same as u did in your edit page

use foreach

```
<?php
 foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if ($value){?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $value->name;?>">
        <input type="text" name="mobile[]" value="<?php echo $value->mobile;?>">
        <input type="text" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $value->email;?>">
        <input type="text" name="doc_name[]" value="<?php echo $value->doc_name;?>">
        <input type="text" name="doc_date[]" value="<?php echo $value->doc_date;?>">
<?php  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting duplicated records because in the bank table I have three records and I have to display all the 3  bank records. I used left join because I have to display the lead information in case of no records on the document or bank table

Comment: I used the result() because in the bank table I have 3 records related to the id 1. If I use row then I will get only one record. What I am trying to do is, I am on the edit page and I have to edit the data.

Comment: Thanks for the update the answer. Sorry for my bad explanation, I have to display lead and document information single and bank data is multiple. I think I have to use foreach for bank data. Also I think I have to change the query also.

Answer (score 0):

//controller: these arrays you can use in your view

```
function leadInfo($id){
$data=array();
$data['lead_detail']=$this->model_name->get_lead_detail_by_id($id);
$data['bank_details']=$this->model_name->get_bank_detail_by_lead_id($id);
$this->load-view('view_page_name',$data);
}
```

//model

```
function get_lead_detail_by_id($id){
$this->db->join('document','document.lead_id=lead.id');
return $this->db->where('lead.id',$id)->get('leads')->row_array();
}

function get_bank_detail_by_lead_id($id){
return $this->db->where('lead_id',$id)->get('bank')->row_array();
}
```